# jQuery text editor inside a tooltip

Tags: jquery, tooltip, text-editor

I'm looking for a simple text editor in jQuery (preferably), that only pops-up as a tooltip once you've selected some text. It should look and behave something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/C2VNr.jpg

Does such an editor exist?
If not, do any of the other jQuery text editors support being embedded inside a tooltip and not only being used as a text-area wrapper?
*(The screenshot is from a Mac app called Byword)*

Comment: i can just say that is easy doable,

Comment: Please do your homework: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

well it's been 2 years. still some people who are searching for will find this useful

https://github.com/raphaelcruzeiro/jquery-notebook

hope this is what you are looking for.